# Renders Appear Black and White

Tags: rendering

Im new to blender, but I've rendered things before and this is the first time this has happened.

In trying to texture and render my city scape, I seem to have screwed up my settings. Can someone tell me why my renders look like garbage?

Ive included render view and 3D view screenshots for reference. 
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: At first glance it looks like sun strength set to high. Try to lower it to 1 or something and check the outcome. If that's not it, then it can be anything and it's hard to tell without checking the file.

Comment: Is this cycles render or blender render?

Comment: It does look like there was a hidden light source that was making a difference, but the buildings themselves still look kind of poor. And Blender Render

Comment: At top right you'll find the "Layout" panel.  That's a sort of asset manager.  Click the eyeball on everything that says it's a lamp or light, to eliminate each in turn.  I use just a single "Hemi" lamp to begin with and change it later.

Comment: the same problem, it turned out I didn’t set the light intensity to 1, but 1000